# Question regarding the $\min(.,.)$ of an $(\varepsilon, \delta)$ proof.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Show that $f(x) = x^2$ is continuous.

My question is not regarding the continuity of this function nor is it regarding how to show it. It’s regarding the way of finding $\delta$ in an $(\varepsilon, \delta)$ proof.

So the so called ”scratchwork” goes like this $$|x -y|< \delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)| < \varepsilon$$ for all $\varepsilon, \delta > 0$.

Now $$|x^2-y^2| = |x-y||x+y|$$ and we have control over $|x-y|$ since $|x-y| < \delta$.

So the problematic term is $|x+y|$. This is where my question is centered, now if I *assume* that $|x-y|<\delta \le 1$ which seems reasonable since I’m interested when $x$ and $y$ are close (I could probably also assume $|x-y| < \pi$, but $1$ seems convinient).

Then $|x-y| < 1 \iff -1<x-y<1 \iff -1+2y<x+y<2y+1$.

So now I have bounded $|x+y| < 2y+1$ **IF** $|x-y|< 1$.

Continuing the ”scratchwork” $$|x^2-y^2| = |x-y||x+y| \\ < \delta (2y+1)$$

which would mean that the natural choice for $\delta =\frac{\varepsilon}{2y+1}$, however I also assumed that $\delta \le 1$ so I need that $\delta = \min(1, \frac{\varepsilon}{2y+1})$.

Now the thing that confuses me is that it seems that $\frac{\varepsilon}{2y+1}$ seems to be fully dependent of the assumption that I made for $\delta \le 1$?

Also what would happen if someone would to choose $\varepsilon = 10$ and say $y = 1$?

Then $$|x^2-1^2| = |x-1||x+1| < \delta(2+1) = 2\delta + \delta =2+1 =3 \ne \varepsilon?$$

This part of taking $\min(.,.)$ confuses me. It seems that it’s required since we made the assumption earlier, but I don’t quite understand it.

Comment: Note that $3 < 10 = \varepsilon$ in this case. You don't need the upper bound in terms of $\delta$ to equal $\varepsilon$, just be less than it (which your logic ensures will always happen).

Comment: Ensures it happen if only $|x-y|<1$ right?

Comment: Yep. If $|x - y| < \delta$, where $\delta$ is the one you constructed as a function of $\varepsilon$ and $y$, then $|x - y| < 1$ is guaranteed.

Comment: A shortcut is to realize that it is easier to stay with linear constraints on $\delta$.  When you select $\delta$ as a function of $\epsilon$ [e.g. $f(\epsilon)$], a common technique is to also have $\delta < 1$.  This implies that $\delta^2 < \delta$.  So, I often use something like $\delta = \min[f(\epsilon), 0.9]$, which is valid and convenient.

Comment: Note that when striving to force more complicated expressions in $\delta$ (i.e. $3\delta^2 + \delta^3$) to be $< \delta$, I will instead use something like $\delta < 0.1$